# Unexpected EOF error

Tags: linux, bash, oracle, shell

I am getting error on below line in shell script i have tried Curly bracket but it wont work, my code is as follow:

```
VAL11=$(${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus -s '/' << EOF
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DBA_USERS WHERE USERNAME=upper('$SCHEMA_NAME');
                EOF
                )
```

I am Getting Below error:

**bkp_on_req_2.sh: line 74: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
bkp_on_req_2.sh: line 170: syntax error: unexpected end of file**

Comment: Try to put EOF at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Try to replace `<< EOF` by `<<-EOF`

Comment: Thanks man it works Fine now

Comment: Which comment worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to NullDev

VAL11=$(${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus -s '/' <<-EOF
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DBA_USERS WHERE USERNAME=upper('$SCHEMA_NAME');
                EOF
                )

Answer (score 0):

The ending tag for heredoc "EOF" should start from the first character of the line.

```
So third line of your code should be
EOF
instead of
           EOF
```